# Store and access files in XLSM package structure

Tags: vba, excel, zip

as part of an excel based VBA project that I am working on I have a reliance on external files. To date I have managed to get around this by either embedding the files or sending them with the spreadsheet.

However as part of this project I have the need to rely on an *.exe file. This poses problems as the OLE exe embeds can be temperamental and sending them alongside can get them filleted by emails.

Since XLSM filled are just zipped folders at their core I was wondering a few questions that was struggling to find answers to:
Are there any reasons why having a custom exe in the package archive will stop it working?
Is there a native way to access the package archive from VBA?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: you description on the problem is a bit obscure. What exactly is the problem? You are trying to fix something that you think is the best solution for the main problem while I think your methodology is just not good and changing it can solve your whole problem easily